# What is behind Google Analytics shopping process stages?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

We have several stages in our shopping process where I do not know what is the exactly meaning of these stages:

```
TRANSACTION
NO_PRODUCT_VIEW
CHECKOUT_WITH_CART_ADDITION
CHECKOUT
ALL_VISITS
ADD_TO_CART_WITHOUT_VIEW
```

Here I assume:

```
ADD_TO_CART <= product added to cart
CHECKOUT_1 <= checkout step 1
CHECKOUT_2 <= checkout step 2
CHECKOUT_3 <= checkout step 3
CHECKOUT_4 <= checkout step 4
CHECKOUT_5 <= checkout step 5
CHECKOUT_6 <= checkout step 6
CHECKOUT_3_WITHOUT_CHECKOUT_2 <= checkout step 3 and jumped over step 2
```

Do you know the meaning of the first blocks stages?

Here a piece of code of our tracking:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    <?php foreach($cartItems as $_quoteItem) : ?>
        <?php if ($_quoteItem->getParentItemId()) continue; ?>

        ga('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($_quoteItem->getSku(), '"') ?>',
            'name': '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($_quoteItem->getName(), '"') ?>',
            'category': '<?php echo $helper->getQuoteCategoryName($_quoteItem) ?>',
            'brand': '<?php echo $helper->getBrand($_quoteItem->getProduct()) ?>',
            'variant': '<?php echo $helper->getVariantProperty($_quoteItem->getProduct()) ?>',
            'price': '<?php echo $_quoteItem->getBasePrice() ?>',
            'quantity': '<?php echo $_quoteItem->getQty() ?>'
        });
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        var paymentMethod = jQuery('input[name="payment[method]"]:checked').next().text();

        ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
            'step': <?php echo $helper->getStepNumber(5) ?>,
            'option': paymentMethod
        });

        ga('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'Checkout',
            eventAction: 'click',
            eventLabel: 'Payment Method - ' + paymentMethod,
            nonInteraction : 1
        });

        ga('send', {
             hitType: 'pageview',
             page: location.pathname + 'payment-information/'
        });
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Analytics E-commerce reporting?

In which case, it looks like these are labels for actions reporting via the e-commerce submit. It has actions that can be recorded for Views, View Details, Add to basket, etc. You can [find details here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#action-types)

Comment: But I do not submit these labels. Well - actually I submit `step` labels, but that is it. I guess GA set these labels by itself and I would like to know what they mean.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of the GA code that's used on page? It's easier to see what's being submitted then and how it links up with the report.

Comment: I added a piece of code. One for enhanced eCom and one for standard tracking.

Comment: They look like labels assigned to e-commerce actions. Products can have views, detailed views, transaction numbers, etc. assigned to them and are then sent with Pageviews / Events to GA where you can pull funnel views. The exact meanings will be according to how they're registered, per the link above (E-commerce actions).

Comment: But we do not set such labels in our code. So GA must have set them by default or with their own logic. And I would like to know their meaning :) Because on this link are none of them described.